# How to store and pass information between list views

Tags: android, android-listview

The functionality of my app can be modeled after something like [wanelo](http://wanelo.com/).

The user will enter a search term for what they want to buy in one Activity. They will get presented with a list of items that match that search term. So, the `ListView` will contain `Item`s. An `Item` has many attributes, the main ones being:

- `id` - corresponds to the `Item`'s id in a database
- `date_modified` - timestamp to know whether the `Item` was updated
- `remote_directory` - a URL to the base directory of the `Item`'s assets like icon and other images. The URL is formatted like this: `http://my.domain.com/items/a1bc234d/` where `a1bc234d` is randomly generated, seeded by `date_modified`.
- `remote_dir_name` - a substring of `remote_directory`. From the example above, this value would be `a1bc234d`.

From the list of search results, the user can mark an item to be viewed later. This will trigger a couple of things:

- First, I want to ad the `Item` to a different `ListView` that represents the `Item`s the user has "downloaded".
- Then, I want to actually download of all of the `Item`'s data: description, all assets in `remote_directory`. These things get stored my app's internal storage in folders `remote_dir_name`: `/data/data/my.app.package.name/files/a1bc234d/`.

These "downloaded" items are meant to be viewable in offline mode.

This "downloaded" `ListView` corresponds to a different Activity and will have list items that show a progress bar of the download status for an `Item`. Also, this `ListView` should be editable: use should be able to delete and re-order the `Item`s in the list.

Finally, the "downloaded" `ListView` needs to be persistent. It should preserve order. The `ListView` of search results need not persist.

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to store the list of `Item`s getting downloaded. The "download" `ListView` needs to know when to update a list item's progress bar if it's getting downloaded. I think it's a little overkill to store the `Item`s in a database because I'll be constantly updating a row's column until the download finishes. How should I pass this download status information between these two `ListView`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I am grasping the whole picture here, but it seems to me that you need two ArrayList fields.

```
List<Item> downloadedItems = new ArrayList<Item>;
List<Item> searchItems = new ArrayList<Item>;
```

then what you need to do is create your own custom ListAdapter for the DownloadListView and create your own custom download_item.xml that you will inflate inside of the ListAdapter. In your case it sounds like this download_item.xml will consist of a textview, and a progressbar, and will need the containing (or top layer) layout set to wrap content.

Now in the on click listener for the SearchListView set it so that it will call a function that will take the item that was tapped and add it to the downloadedItems ArrayList and start the download, as well as refresh the listadapter dataset so it knows to update the items in the list.

The download should be in a AsyncTask, and you will want to use the `@Override publishProgress()` portion of this, so that you can update the status of the download bar.

forgive me for any mis sights or mistakes, I just woke up.

Comment: So, I guess I'm wondering where the ArrayLists should reside. I edited my question to include the fact that the downloadItems listview is in one Activity and the searchItems listview is in another. Typically, the user will search before ever starting the downloadedItems Activity. How should the downloadedItems Activity retrieve the ArrayList? From the searchItems Activity? That seems kind of odd to me... I guess I imagine that downloadedItems should exist in a central location, not as a part of an Activity? Lemme know whether I'm getting at the wrong thing here!

Comment: A couple things. A singleton could be used here. Or you could deserialize the list into a json string and pass that around, or write the array to storage and pull it back out, or write it to a server api and get it back. Honestly a singleton will likely be easiest.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't think to use a singleton. So, I imagine that I want to serialize the list to store it persistently on these events: after an ad is download, after the user "saves" their downloadedItems edits, correct?

Comment: I'm having the download working on a background thread. One download thread per item. Any reason you specified an AsyncTask to do this?

Comment: Easiest way to manage, and has some good features like onpostexecute onpreexecute and publishprogress. Also it eill auto queue and complete them as they come. Its just my personal prference. I tend to only use my own threads in games.